# Searching .txt file for string in C?

Tags: c, search, fgets

I'm working on a function to read line-by-line through a .txt file to search for a provided word. The only string comparison function I can use is strcasecmp, as this is a learning exercise. Here is the function so far...

```
int wordsFindFast(const char const* w){

    int first = 0; //beginning of array
    int last = MAX_NB_WORDS - 1; // number of last element in array
    int middle; // middle of array
    int len = strlen(w);

    while(first <= last) {

        middle = (first + last) / 2;

        if (strncasecmp(w, words[middle], len) == 0) return 1;

        else if(strncasecmp(w, words[middle], len) < 0) {
            last = middle - 1;
        }

        else first = middle + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What's happening now is that the search works fine unless a word is later in the word list, which is nearly 70,000 entries long. I updated the code to use strncasecmp instead of strcasecmp.

The following is defined at the beginning of the code, and MAX_NB_WORDS and MAX_WORD_LENGTH are global variables.

```
static const char*  dataFileName = "words.txt";
```

Comment: This is a really bad way to search, and I would expect to get 0 every time. To find a string with this method, you would need to have the searched string alligned with the multiplicate of `MAX_WORD_LENGTH` and the same length as `MAX_WORD_LENGTH`. You should change your approach. Or maybe you have one word per line to search amongst? In that case, watch out for the newline.

Comment: Look at the contents of "search".  If you're reading a line with the contents `"x"`, for example, "fgets()" will return `"x\n"`.  Which isn't what you want...

Comment: you will implement the `strstr` use by `strcasecmp`.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, both `w` and `search` must start with the same character.  You will be better off looking for the first character of `w` in `search` using `strchr` and then, use `strncasecmp` with the third parameter being equal to `strlen(w)`.  if it does not give you a match, look for the next character starting with the first character of `w` and repeat till you reach a character that leaves a smaller part of `search` to be tested compared to `strlen(w)`.  Here is the code tested with `foobar` and `fubar`.

```
int wordsFindSlow(const char const* w){
    /*
        ROLE            Determines whether a given word is in our words array
                        Implements slow linear algorithm
        PARAMETERS      w   word to look for in the words array
        RETURN VALUE    1   true if the word was found
                        0   false if the word was not found
    */

    char search[] = "This is for testing foobar";

    char * substr = strchr ( search, w[0] );
    while ( substr && strlen ( substr ) >= strlen ( w ) )
    {
        if ( ! strncasecmp ( w, substr, strlen ( w ) ) )
            return ( 1 );

        substr = strchr ( substr + 1, w[0] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have noted that the text file I'm searching is a list of words, alphabetized. Because of that, once the word is found, search and w will begin with the same character anyways, unless I misunderstand you.

Using strncasecmp instead, after initializing and declaring the length of w, worked like a charm for this application.

Comment: Yes, that problem is simpler.  I was able to solve the problem when the word could be anywhere in the string as well.  Just added the code.  It worked as tested.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The only problem I'm having now is that the search doesn't seem to find words that are farther down the list. The list of strings is 69,903 lines long (one word per line). I can't use your method because it uses string functions other than strncasecmp, which I'm not allowed to use. The above method works fine, until I get to words in the Ss. Maybe even sooner...

Comment: This is interesting.  The problem may be somewhere else; this function seems to work fine.  Can you elaborate on your problem.  How big is the list of words that you are searching for?  How big is the file in which you are searching?  Also, are both the lists sorted?

Comment: The file size is 719 KB. I added a few other words in the tests to verify my theory, and it definitely works for words sooner in the list, and fails for ones later. With 69000 entries, it would take a while to isolate where the problem starts. Haha.

Comment: I meant how many entries in the file to be searched?  How many words to search for?  Are both the lists sorted?

Comment: The only list being searched is words.txt, which is defined as "dataFileName" in my code. It contains 69903 lines, each containing one word, and the entire list is alphabetized.

Comment: You seems to open `dataFileName` every time the function is called.  Why don't you open it in the calling function and pass it as parameter.  That way, you will not read the words that you have already read.

Comment: I'm not allowed to modify the calling function, but that is a good idea if I could.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Set breakpoints at both return statements.  Look at the variables "search" and "w" at the breakpoint.  You might also want to look at "errno": `int err = errno`.  If it's non-zero, you have an I/O error. Checking the variables (using the debugger) and checking error status should lead you directly to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the contents of "search". If you're reading a line with the contents "x", for example, "fgets()" will return "x\n". Which isn't what you want...

SUGGESTED CHANGE:

```
int wordsFindSlow(const char const* w){
...
  char search[MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1];
  int len = strlen(w);
  while(fgets(search, MAX_WORD_LENGTH, dataFile)) { 
        if (strncasecmp(w, search, len) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: This works great until I test a word that's farther down my alphabetized list of words, which is nearly 70,000 lines long, with one word per line. Any reason you can think of?

Comment: Your function returns "true" the *first* time it finds a matching word.  Q: What do you want to do differently?

Comment: This function is called multiple times, each with a new word. When the function is called with the word "several", for instance, wordsFindSlow returns a 0, though the word several is in my dataFile.

Comment: If "w" is "several", and if "several" is in your file ... then `fgets()/strncasecmp()` should find it.  `strcasecmp()` will fail, because "several\n" (which is what fgets() returns) is not equal to "several" (what you're searching for).  But `strncasemp()` should definitely work.  Q: Are you sure you're reading that far into the file (without error)?  Q: Have you tried setting breakpoints (for example, at both "return 0" and "return 1" in the debugger, and looking at the variables?

Comment: I updated my original code to make the changes you suggested, although ruling out fgets. I'm using the words[] array that is defined as a static char in the legacy code, which an earlier function uses fgets to fill the array with the words. I'm sure this function works, because it's not one we're allowed to modify. I'm still getting the same results. I'm not sure how to set breakpoints like you're describing.

Comment: Q: What compiler are you using?  MS Visual Studio?  Eclipse/CDT?  Command-line gcc?  Q: What platform are you on?  Windows?  Linux?  Other?  Q: Do you know what your compiler's debugger is?  MSVS?  gdb?  Other?